# Padrão de documentação de código Javascript e geração automática de documentação em IDEs e exportável

Tags: javascript, jquery, documentação

`Java` tem o Javadoc, `PHP` tem PHPDoc e outras linguagens, tem padrões de documentação. Qual padrão mais usado para documentar `javascript`, já integrado a IDEs, de modo que ao usar funções, ele auto-complete o código e haja um meio de gerar documentação automática tendo como base unicamente documentação do código?

Como exibir documentação de bibliotecas de terceiros, como `jQuery`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Para documentar Javascript, recomendo o uso do padão descrito em JSDoc, cuja página com documentação explicativa é http://usejsdoc.org/. Além de dizer em detalhes um padrão que IDEs como Netbeans e Eclipse entendem, o JSDoc também tem uma ferramenta que funciona por linha de comando que lê seu código e converte ele em um manual em HTML pronto para uso.

Como exemplo rápido, olhe o código abaixo

```
/**
 * Esta é uma função de exemplo de uso de JSDoc
 * 
 * @example 
 *   exemplo(3, 5); // 8
 * 
 * @param   {Number} obrigatorio   Parametro obrigatório
 * @param   {Number} [opcional]    Parametro ocional. Note os '[ ]'
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function exemplo (obrigatorio, opcional) {
    var resultado = 0;
    resultado = obrigatorio + (opcional || 0);
    return resultado;
}
```

Para IDE Netbeans 7.4, ao usar a função, irá gerar o seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso do Netbeans e outras IDEs, veja como adicionar sua biblioteca favorita, por exemplo jQuery, a um caminho aonde há o arquivo documentado dele de modo que sua IDE exiba as documentações de contexto. Desse modo vai precisar ver muito menos vezes o Google para algo que já está explicado durante o uso.