# Como documentar CSS?

Tags: css, css3, documentação

Estava documentando o typescript de meu projeto Angular usando [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) me baseando [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5327/padr%C3%A3o-de-documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-javascript-e-gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-autom%C3%A1tica-de-documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o), e fiquei com a seguinte dúvida.

De que forma eu posso fazer a documentação de minhas classes e componentes CSS de meu projeto Angular (e outros projetos futuros), mostrando seus possíveis comportamentos, descrição básica e outros dados relevantes? E existe um gerador de arquivo de documentação, como o [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) do Java?

Exemplo de possível documentação:

```
/**
 * @description modifica comportamento da tag "header"
 * @screensize min 1080
 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px){
    header{ /* aqui ocorre uma mudança de comportamento */ }
}
```

Lembrando que estou pensando no comportamento da documentação baseado no que já vi em outras linguagens, como JavaScript, PHP e Java.

Comment: Eu não estou dizendo que não é uma otima duvida, mas eu me pergunto (e pergunto aos outros) "por que?", quero dizer, como isto ajudaria em algo, eu realmente não consigo ver aonde algo visual que não é "funções" poderiam ser documentáveis, até volta e meia talvez faça sentido. O que seria documentável ao meu ver seria "classes css", mas fora do doc css e talvez fora do "contexto dele", quero dizer, seria os "rules" CSS podem ser usados de muitas formas, complicaria apontar tudo ou estou enganado?

Comment: Na verdade, é justamente por isso que perguntei. Não sei se vou ter algum ganho real ou se só atrapalharia, mas a única forma de saber é testando (eu acho)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu vejo duas formas de documentar, uma seria o guia de boas praticas de uso e metodologias de escrita. E o outro guia a documentação do algo mais próximo de um design system

Comment: @hugocsl isto como disse no meu comentário é documentar as "classes" e não o CSS, o resto é organização do estilo, o que não é documentar, mas fica apenas implicito para facilitar o documentar e só.

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira o que o hugo comentou e respondeu parece util, mas cabe somente as classes, q foi justamente o q eu falei no primeiro comentário ... mas nào é documentar o CSS de fato.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar pois acredito que pergunta seja "ampla demais", não que seja culpa do autor, ao contrário, é um assunto "obscuro", mas em meus comentários anteriores já apontei algumas coisas que podem surgir como problemas, não significa que a pergunta não seja interessante, só que o problema é que CSS pode se usado de muitas formas, cada pessoa trabalha de uma forma com CSS (sério são muitas) e podem vir pessoas com papo de "design" como BEM, mas não é o foco, a pergunta pode ser respondida de muitas formas e nenhuma delas é de fato solução para todo [...]

Comment: [...]  se a pergunta for editada e citar algo mais especifico do que deseja documentar, por exemplo, documentar para equipe as funções, ou documentar o padrão que deve seguir, ou documentar baseado em marcação de comentário e comportamento de "rules" (do CSS), então irei votar para reabrir (se parecer ter melhorado). Quero que entendam que não estou fazendo de maldade e nem nada, participo a muito tempo no site e por experiencia da "saude" do site/comunidade que estou votando, e quando todos ponteiros estiverem certo irei dar o meu apoio para reabrir.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento compreendo seu ponto, e, por isso, corrigi a pergunta. Obrigado pela colaboração, e espero ter sido mais claro

Comment: Otimo, este ponto e a edição mostram como a resposta que surgiu não deveria ter sido feita tão rapidamente, o que você expressou em sua pergunta foi justamente o que entendi no começo, mas parece que foi diferente do que o Hugo entendeu, algumas coisas não é questão de dar "sua contribuição" (2 cents) mas sim de comentar e tentar extrair melhores detalhes do autor da pergunta antes de responder.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento então eu respondi com o que eu achei adequado, e conforme a pergunta foi editada eu tb editei minha resposta. Cada um colabora da forma que acha melhor. Eu entendi um pouco diferente mesmo de vc, por isso segui uma linha que achei que já estaria dentro do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: @hugocsl não leve a mal, não estou falando de sua pessoa ou atitude diretamente, estou falando o que acredito ser o saudável para o site e que esta pergunta tem muitas interpretações, o que caberia uma série de possiveis fechamentos antes de ser de fato respondida, não há o que sentir-se "atacado" (não que tenha se sentido, só checando), só estou falando mesmo em prol da comunidade ;)

Comment: O problema maior aqui é que da mesma forma que o @hugocsl respondeu, daria para termos várias outras sem nenhuma semelhança, cada um pode inventar um jeito novo de responder. Fora isso, o conceito de documentar algo é muito amplo (por exemplo. das coisas que me vieram em mente, nenhuma está na resposta dada). Tem uma parte de recomendação de ferramenta que definitivamente não cabe no escopo. Fora que se um CSS fica complexo a ponto de precisar de documentação, é sinal de que o caminho está às avessas, melhor seria uma ferramenta para gerar o CSS com base em um doc de especificações então.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exitem formas sim de documentar o CSS, eu vejo dois caminhos para isso. O primeiro seria padronizar a escrita do CSS dentro de um time. Algumas empresas já usam isso, inclusive a Google e a Mozilla com seus Style Guides.

Guia da Google https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html projeto no GitHub https://github.com/google/styleguide

Guia da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/CSS

A principal intenção dessa documentação, guia, é manter o padrão de escrita dentro da equipe. Inclusive a documentação pode ainda sinalizar se vai ser usada alguma metodologia com `BEM` ou `DRY`, ou se vai usar algum pré processador como `SCSS` ou `Stylus`.

Outra forma de documentar é mais voltada para gestão de design system como o `Material Design` e o próprio `Bootstrap`. No projeto deles a intenção é facilitar a vida do desenvolvedor, mas principalmente manter o padrão do código, pois a fonte de todos do time é uma só. Isso pode evitar a divergência e inconsistência da forma de escrita do CSS dentro do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Fonte:* https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/

Agora sobre ferramentas para documentar isso o próprio `GitHub` é bastante usada para essas coisas.

Para documentar o `design system` vc pode usar o ZeroHeight https://zeroheight.com/ ou o Outline https://www.getoutline.com/ (existem muitos outros, só procurar no Google )

---

Em ambiente de desenvolvimento vc pode sim deixar comentários e outras instruções. O maior projeto do Git é o Bootstrap, um FrameWork praticamente baseado em CSS e no código fonte existem vários comentários e coisas do tipo. Já nos arquivos de distribuiçao (dist) eles são removidos (provavelmente por algum empacotador usado antes de subir o projeto para produção).

Aqui está um exemple retirado do próprio `GitHub` do `Bootstrap4`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Como falei, esses comentários estão no SCSS ainda, e não devem ir para o ambiente final de produção, ele apenas ajuda a dar manutenção no código e facilita para quem entrar na equipe entender o que está acontecendo no código. Não é uma regra, mas se for da cultura do time vale a pena sim documentar. Principalmente levando em conta a retenção do conhecimento já que em TI a rotatividade é alta, além de ajudar os outros do time a entender o que está sendo feito.

*Fonte:* https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/mixins/_grid.scss

Comment: Isto cai no que eu disse, documentar as classes e não propriamente o CSS. Não é que não seja uma boa resposta, talvez seja exatamente o que o AP procura, mas a questão de começo faz pensar em "mais de uma coisa"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não se trata só de nome de classes, se vc reparar na primeira imagem da resposta envolve tb a forma de escrever etc. Vc sabe que em alguns times existem até forma "corretas" para se escrever um comentário dentro do código etc. Não sei se era exatamente o que o AP procura, mas as referencias talvez ajudem em dar alguma luz

Comment: Sendo classes ou estilo, ainda sim não é nada sobre o "documento" diretamente, documentar para uso até parece ok, mas envolve HTML+CSS, documentar CSS para evolução em equipe ai é "OUTROS 500", e isso não está claro na pergunta. Não adianta batermos o pé que tem solução, ou pq conhecemos uma "coisa" que realmente é o problema definitivo todo, muitas perguntas deveriam amadurecer um pouco antes de receber uma resposta... Eu até concordo que é uma pergunta interessante, mas não quer dizer que realmente deva ser respondida ainda, talvez precisasse de algum amadurecimento.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendo o seu ponto de vista Guilherme, alguns pontos ainda estão obscuros mesmo, estou ai apenas deixando meus 2 cents